# Replace dot with comma in float numbers in text

Tags: javascript

How can I replace float with dot

```
const inputText = 'Text 20.43,4 other 6.90 text 12.334 text. Another text 50.60 text 100,9.'
```

to float with comma, pure javascript?

```
const outPutText = 'Text 20,43,4 other text 12,334 text. Another text 50,60 text 100,9.'
```

Comment: You'll need to use a regex so that you can identify `.` characters within numerical digits, so that the `.` to end the sentence isn't affected.

Comment: The output makes it look like `20,43,4` is one number, but it's actually two. Please also add your effort made so far as a text-based [mcve], so we can help you with where you might have gone wrong

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const x = inputText.replaceAll(/(?<=[0-9])(\.)(?=[0-9])/g, ',')
```

This replaces all `.` within numbers to a comma.